# Image of sum of projections onto a tensor product of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces inside some ambient vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\{\Pi^V_i\}$ and $\{\Pi^W_i\}$ be collections of orthogonal projections from $V$ and $W$ onto subspaces $\tilde{V_i}$ and $\tilde{W_i}$ respectively. Consider now the sum of the projections $$\sum_{i \in A} \Pi^V_i \otimes \Pi^W_i$$ for some restricted index set $A$. This is a projection onto some subspace of $V \otimes W$. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to write this sum of projections as $\Pi_1 \otimes \Pi_2$ for some projection $\Pi_1$ onto a subspace of $V$ and $\Pi_2$ onto a subspace of $W$?
2. What is the relation between the image of the sum $\sum_{i \in A} \Pi^V_i \otimes \Pi^W_i$ and the images of $\{\Pi^V_i\}$ and $\{\Pi^W_i\}$?
3. Is it possible to say anything useful about the image of the sum $\sum_{i \in A} \Pi^V_i \otimes \Pi^W_i$?

Comment: What are you tensoring over?

Comment: Are the $V_i$ supposed to be subspaces of $V$ maybe?

Comment: Yes, the $V_i$ are meant to be subspaces of $V$. Each $\Pi_i^V$ is a projection onto $V_i$.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382829/subspaces-of-a-tensor-product-of-vector-spaces) for an answer to your first question. For 2 and 3 I do not think much can be said.