# Does variable separable method give the complete set of solutions to a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Several of the common partial differential equations encountered in physics are mentioned as easy to solve using the variable separable method. However I do not understand how does one guarantee that the solutions generated using this method is the complete set of solutions. I am finding it quite hard to believe that such a method can produce the entire set of solutions.

Can anyone explain if it indeed does generate the complete set of solutions to a PDE. If not, a counterexample would work. Also, I would like to know if we use this because it is consistent and easy to work with?

Comment: A lot of it comes down to uniqueness of solutions. If you find a solution by any means, and you can prove from the form of the pde that solutions are unique, then you're good to go. This is not always possible, of course.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575205/why-separation-of-variables-works-in-pdes, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163773/when-does-separation-of-variables-yield-basis-of-solution-set