# Can we prove separation of variables applies beforehand (w/o involving BCs)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The approach to solve many PDEs involves the use of the method of *Separation of variables*. This is an assumption regarding the nature of solution that is done beforehand, without proof.

Generally, procedure follows showing existence of such solution and after all calculations its uniqueness (if applies).

- Is there a way to proof before-hand that given a specific PDE, method of separation of variables will give all solutions to that PDE, i.e. will guarantee existence-and-uniqueness?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the usual procedure is to show uniqueness of the PDE regardless of separation of variables. Once you have shown uniqueness, you "try" separation of variables. If it works, then separation of variables give the unique solution. However, I don't think you can show uniqueness using a separation of variables argument only.

Comment: Mm ok, nice insight.. So this if understood correctly this should coincide with proving the problem is well posed, is that correct? - Probably i have some confusion about the fact that usually general solution is made up of linear combination of more solutions (each of them with separate variables), which then is shown to be unique and satisfy boundary conditions (BCs) - unfortunately i rely on really bad notes about these topics, so i'm left with much confusion. But there's not a way, without involving BCs to show that solution in any case will have separation of variables?

Comment: Well posedness includes existence/uniqueness guarantees, yes.  Given that a problem is well posed, you can be confident that just "trying solutions" (either separation of variables or just guessing) is useful at all. Regarding the last question, I don't know.

Comment: Thus may be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163773/when-does-separation-of-variables-yield-basis-of-solution-set